# Get all images from custom post types? - Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, custom-post-type, image-gallery

I'm attemping to create a 'gallery' page for my site, which will display all images from the site, and allow users to filter those by custom post types.

Is it possible to pull in all images from a CPT and attribute them to that particular CPT so they can be filtered between?

I can pull every image from across the site using:

```
$attachments = get_posts( array(
                'post_type' => 'attachment', 
                'post_status' => 'inherit', 
                'post_mime_type' => 'image', 
                'posts_per_page' => -1, 

                'order' => 'DESC' 
            ) );
```

But how could i further customise this to pull images only uploaded to a particular CPT, the desired outcome is i can have a list of filters above that match my post types, so all images across the site can be viewed via the gallery page?

Thanks!

Comment: the problem is that an image can be used in different posts.

Comment: This is true, However as the site has sections such as 'staff' 'projects' etc, it's unlikely that the same image used twice would matter so much, Ideally i'd just like to pull images uploaded to that custom post type.

After some deliberation, I've found a workaround for this, Whilst it's not as lean and clean as it no doubt could be, it does the job for now. Open to any further suggestions if anyone has any. 

My current method was to create a gallery page for each CPT, and inside the CPT loop, run the above get_posts to pull each attachment from that particular CPT. Open to further opinion..